# Creating the thumbnails for an image gallery

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am a back-end developer and I'd like to create a little website using angular and boostrap.

I would like to create a galerie, and I have been looking around to see how it's done. I found a correct example on the following link : https://blueimp.github.io/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery/

In that case, the images are taken from flickr api, which sends 2 different pictures (small and large). The small one is the thumbnail, and when you click on it, it opens the large one.

My question is the following one : let's say I have all my images of different sizes, and that I would like to have thumbnails of those (same size, but responsive !) to create my gallery, what would be the way to do that? With css only?

Comment: check this out http://alijafarian.com/demos/responsive-image-grids-using-css/

Answer (score 0):

Create parent `<div>` with fix width then add `img` inside by applying `width:100%` on image and `height:auto`. Please try to implement the example you found and if you find any issues post with your code.